# How to move an uploaded file

Tags: php, html

I have an HTML web form where users can upload multiple files. I am having trouble with moving the files though.

HTML:

My HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="save.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="500000"/>
    <input type="file" name="uploads[]" multiple="multiple" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
 </form>
```

Save.php:

```
 <?php
     foreach ($_FILES['uploads']['name'] as $file) {
     $target= UPLOADPATH . $file;
     move_uploaded_file($file, $target)
     or die('error with moving the file');
      $file= time() . $_FILES['uploads']['name'];
         echo $file;
     }
```

The problem is with move_uploaded_file(). What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I am actually only seeing the message 'error with moving the file'

Comment: Check logs and bring here any error you find.

Comment: Also, echo out $target and see if that actually exists.

Comment: Check your file path. Make sure it is true and the file exists there. make sure your web service and php user have the appropriate permissions to both directories.

Comment: The file path is good. How do I check the logs?

Comment: Does `UPLOADPATH` end with a `/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as below, you need to pass first parameter as file source

```
foreach ($_FILES['uploads']['name'] as $key => $file) {
 $target= UPLOADPATH . $file;

 move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploads']['tmp_name'][$key], $target)
 or die('error with moving the file');
  $file= time() . $_FILES['uploads']['name'];
     echo $file;
 }
```

Comment: Yes. I just noticed he might not be passing the fully qualified file path and name in the first parameter. Check the manual. http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: Yes he need to pass file source which comes as tmp_name

Comment: can you paste what you get in var_dump($_FILES) ??

Comment: array(1) { ["uploads"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(25) "moon-over-mistral-sky.jpg" } ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\phpD322.tmp" } ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(881428) } } }